# Sending an API request with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, request

I've been trying to hit an API and get some data back from it (It's a free API not my own). So I've got my API token and I've had a look around and found that npm package `request` seems to be the best.

Within one of my routes I have,

```
request({
    uri: "https://app.url-to-api:443/api/list-of-data",
    method: "GET",
    api_token: "my-api-token",
    timeout: 10000,
    followRedirect: true,
    maxRedirects: 10
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

So I'm getting `"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."` back which is obviously because my API Token isn't getting passed through.

This might be a stupid question, but where do I actually put the API token to validate my request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In request it would be something like this:

```
request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'bearer': 'bearerToken'
  }
});
```

More details on what you can do with request are in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#http-authentication).

Comment: thank you! This looks like what I'm looking for. Stupid question, though, how can I `console.log()` my data out? So on the docs they do `.on('error',function(err){console.log(err)}` so instead of `error` I changed it to `success` but i'm not getting anything in my console window

Comment: .on in javascript is used for event, you need to listen for error not success, listen for response in case of success.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass api tokens in request headers please see the documentation for [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#http-authentication)

```
var request = require('request');


var options = {
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/request/request',
  headers: {
    'Access-Token': 'request'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info.stargazers_count + " Stars");
    console.log(info.forks_count + " Forks");
  }
}



request(options, callback);
```